# XCode "An error occurred during upload, rsync: failed"

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7, cocoapods

The last archives I've made turn out into this error 
[image: this error]

Logs show this information (app name and route omitted on this log)

```
    2016-06-28 08:53:48 +0000 [MT] Upload failed for archive App with issues:
(
    "<IDEDistributionIssue: severity(error), error(Error Domain=ITunesSoftwareServiceErrorDomain Code=-19066 \"The path '/route/App.ipa' does not contain a file.\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The path '/route/App.ipa' does not contain a file., NSLocalizedFailureReason=Unable to validate your application.})>"
)
```

This is where the error occurs according to the log. It happens at a random framework each time

```
rsync: recv_generator: mkdir "/var/folders/ls/hdnz28rx7bb4929q6z4m37gc0000gn/T/XcodeDistPipeline.nwz/GaugeKit.framework/GaugeKit.bundle" failed: Result too large (34)
*** Skipping everything below this failed directory ***
2016-06-28 09:06:14 +0000  GaugeKit.framework/_CodeSignature/
2016-06-28 09:06:14 +0000  
sent 286 bytes  received 38 bytes  648.00 bytes/sec
total size is 388.45K  speedup is 1227.70
2016-06-28 09:06:14 +0000  rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) at /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync-47/rsync/main.c(992) [sender=2.6.9]
2016-06-28 09:06:14 +0000  /usr/bin/rsync exited with 23
```

It happens when I try to upload to App Store, if I archive for Ad Hoc it doesn't happen and it always happens when it's processing symbols for pods (but not on same pod, just a random pod each time). I'm using Cocoapods 1.0.1 and frameworks (`use_frameworks!`) and only if I archive with app symbols. Bitcode is deactivated as some pods don't support it.

Any hints about this error? It keeps happening on two different apps with different pods.

EDIT: just to clarify, this error happens while generating the ipa file, for AppStore submission. Both Apps are now published. This error happens randomly while processing symbols (step before code signing) for frameworks (pods) generated and it doesn't happen the same on the same library, it's just random, and while keeping trying I can manage to upload to the AppStore, but I'd like to know how to prevent the head banging with this error.

Comment: Where can I see the logs because when I select 'Show logs' it opens a file called 'T' with heaps of folders and files. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was getting this error sporadically. When you uncheck the "Include symbols" checkbox it does fix it.

But if you're like me and want the symbols to be sent to Apple, I found another strange fix: Unplug your phone from the Mac when submitting the archive to Apple.

Strange.

Answer (score 2):

I get this issue on XCode 8.3.1 if my device is connected.  If I unplug my device and try again it uploads without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

You should upload binary by `Application Loader`. I got many problems with Xcode uploader ! I tried `Application Loader` and it's fine.

Comment: I can't use Application Loader as it happens in the process of generating the ipa file, so I only have a .xcarchive file. It happens both on "upload to App Store" and "export" processes

Comment: Why you can't use Application Loader ?

Comment: As far as I know Application Loader requires an ipa file to upload, right? As stated before this error happens in the process of creating the ipa file so I have no ipa, just the xcarchive. If I try to export an ipa from the archive this error also happens. When XCode manages to create the ipa (after several unsucesful attempts) it uploads always OK, but my problem is it fails while creating the ipa

Comment: You will upload this app to Appstore or private store ? If it's for appstore, and you failed when export IPA, I think you should resolve the problem because the Apple server will validate the binary and reject it. The problem may be related to certificate and provisioning.

Comment: I'm uploading to AppStore. It's not certificate or provisioning related as if i keep trying I manage to upload it properly and both Apps are published on the Store now

Comment: You can send me the error when you export it to IPA ?

Answer (score 0):

I know it sounds simplistic, but try rebooting.

[Edit 2: Turns out this was coincidental, rebooting and deleting those files doesn't always work. I've found now that if I just retry it several times, it eventually works.]

[Edit: rebooting is painful. I've since found that deleting the /var/folders/?/ XCodeDistPipeline.* directories has worked as well.]

My log showed that rsync was complaining of a file being too large, and when I looked at /var/folders, I found Xcode was leaving old folders. After rebooting, many of them had been pruned, and I was able to submit without this error.

Comment: It's worse: rsync during symbolication is sporadically failing on a stat(2) or mkdir(2) syscall with ERANGE (34).  This is not a documented error code for these calls, and is just a POSIX error propagated through rsync from the failed syscall (per a review of Apple's published rsync source for macOS 10.12.3).  This suggests some obscure problem at the filesystem or even kernel level is being triggered.  The disk in question had >100GB free and passed a Disk Utility/First Aid filesystem scan all-green.

Comment: Good catch. I had a green disk scan as well, and about 20Gb free. In my case the symbolication is against some fairly large frameworks, so maybe file size related? This is still happening regularly to me; repeating the process multiple times eventually succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

I found that, for me at least, I was getting an rsync error because my laptop was out of storage space for files being generated.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the

> source="$(readlink "${source}")"

With

> source="$(readlink -f "${source}")"

Did not resolve my issue. I was facing multiple other issues due to lack of permission in the Xcode 15.

If someone facing this kind of error on Xcode 15, Search **ENABLE_USER_SCRIPT_SANDBOXING** in build settings of Pods project. In my case setting it to **NO** resolved the issue.

**Ref** : https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/731041?answerId=755722022#755722022