# Flutter app uploading to AppStore Xcode error: Rsync failed

Tags: xcode, flutter, xcode11

Whenever I try to Validate App after Archiving it in Xcode I get the following error popup:

```
Rsync failed
```

It then shows a 'Show logs.' button but when I select that it opens a folder called 'T' which contains many files and folders.

How can I see the logs that I need to fix this error?

Using Xcode 11.5

Comment: Please add your `flutter doctor` output to your question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38071696/xcode-an-error-occurred-during-upload-rsync-failed did you check this?

Comment: @FurkanKURT yes I saw this but my question is more so how I can see the actual error logs, if you see In the screenshot of that question it shows the Rsync error and a show logs button. That opens up a folder called ‘T’ with heaps of other files in there. But I can’t seem to find the actual log so I can fix the error. Thanks again.

Comment: I understand, if u share the file names maybe I can help u.

Comment: what is your flutter version?

Answer (score 0):

Usually the problem with Rsync is with the pods and the build itself. Try to run flutter clean, run pod install inside the ios folder, test your app in a real devidce, build the app and try again.